# i want to install csh but the following error appears

Tags: software-installation

I need to install Kdevelop and csh package on my ubuntu 13.10 os but couldn't locate package and following errors appears;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package
```

Comment: what exact command did you enter to get that error? Did you spell the package name correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked and both packages are in the repositories, so the only two things I can imagine:

1. You need to *update* your package list:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install csh kdevelop
   ```
2. Maybe these packages are in the universe or multiverse repository, and you neet to enable'm. Go to Software Sources (you can find it typing in the dash) and enable them:

[image]

My screenshot is in `Catalan`, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Then again, re-run both commands:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install csh kdevelop
```